# servlet, jsp and user feedback from form

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have been straggling as to how to implement the following scenario. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

I have a form that the user fills in. Using jquery it is validated as much as possible before sending to the server. When the submit button is click the form is send to a servlet.

The servlet will then check the db and if everything is still ok will add it sends the relevant information to a jsp that will then display a new page. 
The part that I can seem to nail down is if the servlet finds an error. In that case an error, a message should popup to the user and the page should not change. I know this may not be possible.

If its not possible are there any good web design guidance on giving user feedback after they submit a form and how to implement it using servlet and jsp.

Thanks

Alexis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to return (forward) the request to the same JSP page with the form. You can use `${param}` to redisplay the original input. You can use `request.setAttribute()` in the servlet to set some data in the request scope which you in turn can display in the JSP page.

Here's a kickoff example of such a JSP page representing a login form:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

...

    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.username)}">
    <br>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.password)}">
    <br>
    <span class="error">${error}</span>
```

(the [`fn:escapeXml`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) is mandatory to prevent from [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) [attacks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) when redisplaying user-controlled input)

In a servlet which is postprocessing the request, you can handle the login roughly as follows:

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
User user = userDAO.find(username, password);
if (user != null) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user); // User found, login it.
    response.sendRedirect("home"); // Redirect to home page.
} else {
    request.setAttribute("error", "Unknown username/password, please try again"); // Set message which you display in ${error}
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response); // Redisplay the same JSP page.
}
```

Note that the above example displays the error embedded on the same page and is not displaying an alert, since alerts are bad user experience. If you really insist in displaying an alert, then you can grab JSTL `c:if` tag to print an alert conditionally:

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <script>alert('${error}');</script>
</c:if>
```

Again, this is not the normal practice.

#### See also:

- [Beginning and intermediate JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)
- [More advanced example of JSP/Servlet form with database interaction and validation](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-use-in-jspservlet.html)
- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/01/hidden-features-of-jspservlet.html)

Comment: thanks for that. This is what i needed.

I will follow your advice and will take out the alert box and highlight the text field in red or something with a small error message next to it..

thanks again
alexis

Answer (score 0):

You can use RequestDispatcher's include()/forward() methods for this.

few examples hope this will help.
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/0280__RequestDispatcher.htm
http://www.tutorialsto.com/index.php/software/vc/i-finally-realized-the-mvc-with-requestdispatcher.html
http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=492819